# jqgrid dynamic group headers not aligned

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am setting three level group headers dynamically.But they do not come out aligned.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0fcqfnm7/2/)

groupHeadersArr is a two dimensional array such that

```
    // groupHeadersArr[i][0] -> row 1 of header.
    // groupHeadersArr[i][1] -> row 2 of header.
```

Here is the code:

```
    var colNames = ["id", "userid", "totalsales", "totalsales", "totalsales"];
    var colModel = [
      {
        "name": "id"
      },
      {
        "name": "userid__"
      },
      {
        "name": "2015-03-02_2015-03-02_totalsales__"
      },
      {
        "name": "2015-03-03_2015-03-03_totalsales__"
      },
      {
        "name": "2015-03-04_2015-03-04_totalsales__"
      }
    ]
    // groupHeadersArr[i][0] -> row 1 of header.
    // groupHeadersArr[i][1] -> row 2 of header.
    var groupHeadersArr = [
      [
        [
          {
            "startColumnName": "2015-03-02_2015-03-02_totalsales__",
            "numberOfColumns": 1,
            "titleText": "2015-03-02"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "startColumnName": "2015-03-02_2015-03-02_totalsales__",
            "numberOfColumns": 1,
            "titleText": "2015-03-02"
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          {
            "startColumnName": "2015-03-03_2015-03-03_totalsales__",
            "numberOfColumns": 1,
            "titleText": "2015-03-03"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "startColumnName": "2015-03-03_2015-03-03_totalsales__",
            "numberOfColumns": 1,
            "titleText": "2015-03-03"
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          {
            "startColumnName": "2015-03-04_2015-03-04_totalsales__",
            "numberOfColumns": 1,
            "titleText": "2015-03-04"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "startColumnName": "2015-03-04_2015-03-04_totalsales__",
            "numberOfColumns": 1,
            "titleText": "2015-03-04"
          }
        ]
      ]
    ];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table')
            .jqGrid({
                colModel: colModel,
                colNames: colNames,
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                maxHeight: 320,
                toolbar: [true, "top"],
                beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
                    return false;
                },
                hoverrows: false
            });
            groupHeadersArr.forEach( function( val ) {
                // console.log( val );
                $("#table").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                    useColSpanStyle: true, 
                    groupHeaders: val[0]
                });
                $("#table").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                  useColSpanStyle: true,
                  groupHeaders:val[1]
                });
            });
    });
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code?

P.S. : Desired look of headers for this particular example.[image]

Comment: The code which you post calls `setGroupHeaders` 6 times. Thus you creates 6-level group headers instead of 3-level headers. It's not full clear for me which final look of the grid you want to have. I don't understand the goal of the usage `numberOfColumns: 1` everywhere. You will have **no grouping of columns** in the way and one will have just one text over the another one. By the way you should add "free-jqgrid" tag additionally to "jqgrid" if you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)

Comment: @Oleg I have attached the final look of the multilevel headers.I am using 'numberOfColumns:1' when top group header has only one subheader.i.e., one to one correspondence between top and bottom headers.Though this may not make sense but since the values are dynamically created, this is the corner case that's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just reorganize the structure of `groupHeadersArr`. You group the items by columns instead of grouping by rows which require `setGroupHeaders`.

The modified demo would be https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0fcqfnm7/3/ which displays like

[image]

(the above line exists because you use `toolbar: [true, "top"]` option). It uses the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colNames = ["id", "userid", "totalsales", "totalsales", "totalsales"];
    var colModel = [
      { "name": "id" },
      { "name": "userid__" },
      { "name": "2015-03-02_2015-03-02_totalsales__" },
      { "name": "2015-03-03_2015-03-03_totalsales__" },
      { "name": "2015-03-04_2015-03-04_totalsales__" }
    ]
    var groupHeadersArr = [
        [
            {
                "startColumnName": "2015-03-02_2015-03-02_totalsales__",
                "numberOfColumns": 1,
                "titleText": "2015-03-02"
            },
            {
                "startColumnName": "2015-03-03_2015-03-03_totalsales__",
                "numberOfColumns": 1,
                "titleText": "2015-03-03"
            },
            {
                "startColumnName": "2015-03-04_2015-03-04_totalsales__",
                "numberOfColumns": 1,
                "titleText": "2015-03-04"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "startColumnName": "2015-03-02_2015-03-02_totalsales__",
                "numberOfColumns": 1,
                "titleText": "2015-03-02"
            },
            {
                "startColumnName": "2015-03-03_2015-03-03_totalsales__",
                "numberOfColumns": 1,
                "titleText": "2015-03-03"
            },
            {
                "startColumnName": "2015-03-04_2015-03-04_totalsales__",
                "numberOfColumns": 1,
                "titleText": "2015-03-04"
            }
        ]        
    ];
    var $grid = $('#table');
    $grid.jqGrid({
        colModel: colModel,
        colNames: colNames,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        maxHeight: 320,
        toolbar: [true, "top"],
        beforeSelectRow: function() {
            return false;
        },
        hoverrows: false
    });
    groupHeadersArr.forEach( function( val ) {
        $grid.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true, 
            groupHeaders: val
        });
    });
});
```